# Como utilizar um único formulário para cadastrar um novo usuário e alterar dados de um usuário existente no sistema?

Tags: php, jquery, html5, ajax

Olá. 
Eu tenho um formulário e uma tabela (que lista os funcionários da empresa).

Quando eu clico em um TR (de seu respectivo funcionário) na tabela, os dados do formulário são preenchidos com os dados do funcionário da empresa. Então, se eu modificar algum dado do funcionário, eu envio os dados para um arquivo PHP e faço um update na tabela do banco de dados e atualizado os dados deste funcionário. Até ai tudo bem. (Ou seja, o botão "ALTERAR" que leva ao update está funcionando normalmente)

Só que eu gostaria de que quando eu NÃO clicasse da tr da tabela, e o formulário estivesse em branco, eu inserir dados nele e cadastrar um novo funcionário (realizar um INSERT).

Estou quebrando um pouco a cabeça aqui. Pensei em colocar dois botões submits, um sendo o "ALTERAR" e outro sendo o "CADASTRAR". E cada um deles chamar um função diferente do jQuery para eu conseguir usar um AJAX específico que se comunique com arquivos PHP diferentes.

Mas não estou conseguindo ver uma boa lógica nisso. Se alguém puder me ajudar, eu ficaria grato. (Acredito que não seja algo difícil)

**Abaixo segue o código que estou utilizando até então.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // AO CARREGAR A PÁGINA, CHAMAR A FUNÇÃO QUE PREENCHE OS FUNCIONÁRIOS
  $(function() {
    preencher_funcionarios();

  });


  //Evento que ocorre ao submitar o formulário
  $('#formulario-cadastrar-funcionarios').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formulario_cadastrar_funcionarios = $(this);
    var retorno_cadastrar_funcionarios = cadastrar_funcionarios(formulario_cadastrar_funcionarios);

  });


  //Função que faz o cadastro do funcionário
  function cadastrar_funcionarios(cadastrarfuncionarios) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "banco/banco-vision/pagina-cadastrar-funcionarios/incluir-funcionarios.php",
      type: "post",
      data: cadastrarfuncionarios.serialize(),
      cache: false,

    }).done(function(retornousuarios) {
      var funcionarios = "";

      $.each($.parseJSON(retornousuarios), function(chave, funcionarios_cadastrados) {
        //Aqui atualizamos a tabela da lista dos funcionários
        //CRIANDO AS LINHAS COM OS TD DA TABELA QUE SÃO O RESULTADO NA CONSULTA AO BANCO 

        funcionarios += '<tr id="' + funcionarios_cadastrados.codigo + '">';

        funcionarios += '<td>' + funcionarios_cadastrados.usuario + '</td>';
        funcionarios += '<td>' + funcionarios_cadastrados.EMPRESA_ORIGEM + '</td>';
        funcionarios += '<td>' + funcionarios_cadastrados.departamento + '</td>';

        funcionarios += '</tr>';

      });

      $('#registros-funcionarios-cadastrados').html(funcionarios);

      alert(retornousuarios);

    }).fail(function() {
      console.log("Erro ao atualizar");

    }).always(function() {


    });

  }





});
```

```html
<?php
 
 
 
 //CHAMANDO O ARQUIVO DE CONEXÃO COM O BANCO DE DADOS
 require_once("banco/conexao/conexao-com-banco.php"); 
 require_once("banco/validador-de-login/validador-login.php"); 
 
 
?>

  <?php

require_once("banco/banco-vision/pagina-cadastrar-funcionarios/preencher-select-departamento.php"); 

?>



    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

    <head>
      <title>T-Vision</title>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=devide-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <script src="_jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <!-- ARQUIVO JQUERY -->
      <link href="_css-cadastrar-funcionarios/pagina-cadastrar-funcionarios/cadastrar-funcionarios.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- ARQUIVO CSS DO -->
      <link href="_bootstrap4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- ARQUIVO CSS DO BOOTSTRAP -->

    </head>


    <body>

      <!-- INTRODUÇÃO VIDEO - ANDREWS-->
      <!--
  <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
     <source src="_videos/Intro_Login.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  -->

      <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row" id="row-filtros-funcionario">

          <!-- DIV COM O FORMULÁRIO DE LOGIN -->

          <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" id="cadastrar-funcionarios">

            <h2>INFORMAÇÕES DO FUNCIONÁRIO</h2>

            <form action="" method="post" id="formulario-cadastrar-funcionarios">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="usuario">Usuario:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Digite o nome do usuário" required autofocus />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="senha-usuario">Senha:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="senha-usuario" name="senha-usuario" pattern="^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@#$])[a-zA-Z0-9@#$]{8,50}$" placeholder="Digite a senha do usuário" required />
                <span style="font-size: 70%">(A senha deve conter no mínimo uma letra maiúscula, uma minúscula, um número e um caracter especial (@, # ou $). A senha deve possuir no mínimo 8 caracteres.)</span>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email-usuario">Email:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email-usuario" name="email-usuario" placeholder="Digite o email do usuário" required />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="departamento-usuario">Departamento:</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="departamento-usuario" id="departamento-usuario" required>
                  <?php
           while($linha_departamento = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_departamento))
           {
          ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $linha_departamento[" DEPARTAMENTO "];?>">
                      <?php echo $linha_departamento["DEPARTAMENTO"];?>
                    </option>

                    <?php
           }
          ?>
                </select>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="empresa-origem-usuario">Empresa Origem:</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="empresa-origem-usuario" id="empresa-origem-usuario" required>
                  <?php
           while($linha_empresa_origem = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_empresa_origem))
           {
          ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $linha_empresa_origem[" EMPRESA_ORIGEM "];?>">
                      <?php echo $linha_empresa_origem["EMPRESA_ORIGEM"];?>
                    </option>

                    <?php
           }
          ?>
                </select>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="tipo-usuario">Tipo de Usuário</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="tipo-usuario" id="tipo-usuario" required>
                  <option id="usuariocomum" value="usuariocomum">USUARIO COMUM</option>
                  <option id="supervisor" value="supervisor">SUPERVISOR</option>
                  <option id="administrador" value="administrador">ADMINISTRADOR</option>
                </select>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="status-usuario">Status do Usuário</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="status-usuario" id="status-usuario" required>
                  <option id="ativo" value="ativo">ATIVO</option>
                  <option id="inativo" value="inativo">INATIVO</option>
                </select>
              </div>

              <input type="hidden" name="cod-funcionario" id="cod-funcionario" value="1000">

              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="btn btn-md btn-primary" type="submit" name="cadastrar-funcionarios" id="cadastrar-funcionarios" value="CADASTRAR FUNCIONÁRIO">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="btn btn-md btn-success" type="submit" name="salvar-funcionarios" id="salvar-funcionarios" value="ALTERAR FUNCIONÁRIO">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="btn btn-md btn-danger" type="reset" name="resetar-campos" id="resetar-campos" value="LIMPAR">
              </div>


            </form>

            <div id="mensagem">
              <h5>
                <?php echo $mensagem ?>
              </h5>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>


        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" id="listagem-funcionarios">

          <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" id="resultado-funcionarios-cadastrados">

            <thead class="">
              <tr>
                <th>FUNCIONÁRIO</th>
                <th>EMPRESA</th>
                <th>DEPARTAMENTO</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody id="registros-funcionarios-cadastrados">

            </tbody>

          </table>

        </div>


      </div>

      <script src="_jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <!-- ARQUIVO JQUERY -->
      <script src="_bootstrap4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="_scripts/script-vision/script-pagina-cadastrar-funcionarios/cadastrar-funcionarios.js"></script>



    </body>
    <!-- FIM DO BODY -->

    </html>
    <!-- FIM DO HTML -->

    <?php
 // Fechando Conexão
 
 mysqli_close($conecta);
  
?>


      <!-- ARQUIVO PHP QUE FAZ A ALTERAÇÃO DOS DADOS DO FUNCIONÁRIO incluir-funcionario.php -->


      <?php
 
 date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
 require_once "../../conexao/conexao-com-banco.php";
   
 date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+3');
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "", "pt_BR.utf-8");
   
   
 //PREENCHE AS VARIÁVEIS COM OS DADOS VINDOS DOS CAMPOS DO FORMULÁRIO
 
 $usuario_alterar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'usuario', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
 
 $funcionario_alterar = $usuario_alterar;
 
 $senha_alterar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'senha-usuario', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

 $email_alterar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email-usuario', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);  
   
 $departamento_alterar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'departamento-usuario', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
 
 $empresa_origem_alterar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'empresa-origem-usuario', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  
 $tipo_usuario_alterar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'tipo-usuario', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
 
 $status_alterar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'status-usuario', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
 
 $cod_alterar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cod-funcionario', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
 
 
 if($status_alterar == "ativo")
 {
  $status_usuario_alterar = 1;
 }
 else if($status_alterar == "inativo")
 {
  $status_usuario_alterar = 0;
 }
 
   
 if($tipo_usuario_alterar == "usuariocomum")
 {
  $update_alterar_usuario = "UPDATE tbl_usuarios set funcionario = '$funcionario_alterar', usuario = '$usuario_alterar', senha = '$senha_alterar', email = '$email_alterar', DEPARTAMENTO = '$departamento_alterar', EMPRESA_ORIGEM = '$empresa_origem_alterar', USUARIO_COMUM = 1, SUPERVISOR = 0, ADMINISTRADOR = 0, ATIVO = $status_usuario_alterar, imagem = 'Sem Imagem' WHERE CODIGO = $cod_alterar";
 
 }
 
 else if($tipo_usuario_alterar == "supervisor")
 {
  $update_alterar_usuario = "UPDATE tbl_usuarios set funcionario = '$funcionario_alterar', usuario = '$usuario_alterar', senha = '$senha_alterar', email = '$email_alterar', DEPARTAMENTO = '$departamento_alterar', EMPRESA_ORIGEM = '$empresa_origem_alterar', USUARIO_COMUM = 1, SUPERVISOR = 1, ADMINISTRADOR = 0, ATIVO = $status_usuario_alterar, imagem = 'Sem Imagem' WHERE codigo = $cod_alterar";
 }
 
 else if($tipo_usuario_alterar == "administrador")
 {
  $update_alterar_usuario = "UPDATE tbl_usuarios set funcionario = '$funcionario_alterar', usuario = '$usuario_alterar', senha = '$senha_alterar', email = '$email_alterar', DEPARTAMENTO = '$departamento_alterar', EMPRESA_ORIGEM = '$empresa_origem_alterar', USUARIO_COMUM = 1, SUPERVISOR = 1, ADMINISTRADOR = 1, ATIVO = $status_usuario_alterar, imagem = 'Sem Imagem' WHERE codigo = $cod_alterar";
 }
 
 
 
 $result_update_alterar_usuario = mysqli_query($conecta, $update_alterar_usuario);
 
 $affected_rows = 0;
 $affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($conecta);
   

 if($affected_rows != 0)
 { 
  $select_usuarios = "SELECT * from tbl_usuarios";
  $lista_usuarios = mysqli_query($conecta, $select_usuarios);
    
  if(!$lista_usuarios)
  {
   die("Erro no Banco - Erro no Select na tabela tributações");
   exit;
  }
 
  $retorno_usuarios = array();
  while($linha_usuarios = mysqli_fetch_object($lista_usuarios))
  {     
   $retorno_usuarios[] = $linha_usuarios;     
  }   
 }
 
 else
 { 
  die('O funcionário não foi cadastrado - Tente Novamente');
  exit();
 }
   
 echo json_encode($retorno_usuarios); 


?>
```

**Abaixo temos imagens do sistema**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uma possível solução seria, quando clicar em um tr, enviar por url algum dado, pode ser o id, código, o que achar melhor, e quando for adicionar novo, você não envia nada. exemplo:

```
<button type="button"><a href="exemplo.php?id='.$id.'"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></a></button>
```

No código do formulário você valida se existe o get com o dado id como no meu exemplo, se existir você coloca o botão para alterar se não o botão fica como inserir, e no codigo do js vc implementa para qual ajax vai enviar. como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php
  // verifica se existe o id na url se existir ele faz a consulta no banco buscando os dados do que vai ser alterado para poder preencher o formulário
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
      $id = $_GET['id'];
      $sql = $pdo->prepare("exemplo..");
      $sql->execute();
      foreach ($sql as $row) {
          $exemplo1 = $row['exemplo1'];
          $exemplo2 = $row['exemplo2'];
      }
    }
    ?>

    // nos campos do fomulário você verifica se existe a variavel buscada no banco se existir vai mostrar ela no imput caso contrario ele vem vazio
    <label>exemplo1</label>
    <?php
      if (isset($exemplo1)) {        
          echo '<input type="text"  id="exemplo1" value=' . $exemplo1 . '>';
      } else {
          echo ' <inputtype="text" id="exemplo1">';
      }
    ?>

//no final do arquivo quando for ter o botão de enviar você conferi se existe o id.

<?php
  if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    echo '<button type="button" id="btn_atualizar">Enviar</button>';
  } else {
    echo '<button type="button" id="btn_enviar">Enviar</button>';
  }
?>
```